# React Native: Android back button does not work when the screen re mounts

Tags: android, react-native

I used `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUnmount` for android button to work. 
But when I come again to the same screen from another screen, the function which I have placed in android back button does not work. It works initially when I load the screen for first time but when I go to another screen and come back to that screen again the function which I have placed in back button does not work.

when I tap on the nav bar below. When I go to the other screen and come back it is working fine.. But when I tap on the nav bar and navigate to other screen and then come back again to the screen then the function does not help!! I am in a great dilemma. Particularly to make it clear: I am on the home screen, I go-to description of the post, and then come back to home screen back button function of android works..But when I tap on the nav bar, navigate to other screen and then come back clicking on the nav bar, the function does not work. –

```
async componentDidMount() {
     BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress',this.handleBackButtonClick);
}    
componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

async handleBackButtonClick() {

Alert.alert(
    'Exit the app?',
    'Are you sure you want to exit the app?',

    [
      {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
      {text: 'OK', onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp()},
    ],
    { cancelable: false }
  )

}
```

Comment: How are you navigating between screens? There are some routers that do not unmount the component, so when you go back it won't hit the DidMount method.

Comment: @ageoff I am using stack navigation of react native. No third party is used. And particularly I have to call the component after it unmounts.. The page loads the component is loaded in did mount and afterwards  in the un mount function it dismounts. Here arises the problem that after un mounting the component how can i reuse that when i re-enter the screen from some another screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure which method calls when you come back again to the screen.

```
componentWillMount() {

    console.log("componentWillMount");


    this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'willBlur',
      payload => {
        console.log('willBlur', payload);
      }
    );

    this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'willFocus',
      payload => {
        console.debug('willFocus', payload);
      }
    );

    this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'didFocus',
      payload => {
        console.debug('didFocus', payload);
      }
    );

    this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'didBlur',
      payload => {
        console.debug('didBlur', payload);
      }
    );
}



componentDidMount(){
    console.log("componentDidMount")
}

componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log("componentDidUpdate")
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    console.log("componentWillUnmount")
}
```

then run your function.

Answer (score 1):

You just use `addListener` for navigation.

Like this:

```
componentDidMount() {

    this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'didFocus',
      payload => {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress',this.handleBackButtonClick);
      }
    );

}
```

follow this link: [addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time but the error arises when I tap on the nav bar below. When I go to the other screen and come back it is working fine.. But when I tap on the nav bar and navigate to other screen and then come back again to the screen then the function does not help!! I am in a great dilemma. Particularly to make it clear: I am on the home screen, I go-to description of the post, and then come back to home screen back button function of android works..But when I tap on the nav bar, navigate to other screen and then come back clicking on the nav bar, the function does not work.

Comment: do not worry. It's not a big problem, it will surely be solved. I had this problem too. Step-by-step we go together @RishavKumar